# .NET Test Explorer tree keeps spinning forever with Selenium Chrome WebDriver

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, nunit, test-explorer

Only when using Selenium WebDrive and if the Chrome is opened as per the following code:

```
IWebDriver driver;
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

then, the progress indicator on the test tree will keep on spinning forever. If I don't open Chrome by  commenting out the `new ChromeDriver()`, it works fine.

Following are components used:

1. VSCode Extension .NET Core Test Explorer v0.7.7
2. Dotnet sdk version: .NET 5.0
3. Unit test framework: NUnit 3.13.1
4. The link to the repo with the issue: https://github.com/tarekahf/NUnit-Selenium
5. Selenium WebDriver: 4.1.0

See the snapshot below.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Tarek

[image: NUnit test keeps spinning]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue but fixed it by adding a new method with the `[OneTimeTearDown]` attribute that explicitly quits the `IWebDriver` by calling it's `Quit()` method. The whole method looks as follows:

```
[OneTimeTearDown]
public void Teardown()
{
    _chromeDriver.Quit();
}
```